# Colour of progress bar in fileInput -- Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to change the colour of the upload progress bar in the fileInput widget in Shiny. I am a bit of a shiny novice and have scoured the internet with no results. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to play with the CSS: see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html. Haven't used shiny much so not sure about how you'd track down the class/ID of the progress bar.

Comment: @Marius Yeah have tried the CSS route but couldn't find the progress bar ID, like you say. Hopefully there are some CSS gurus out there who see this question!

Comment: Playing around with "Inspect element" on [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html), I get `<div id="file1_progress" class="progress progress-striped shiny-file-input-progress" style="visibility: visible;">`. So it looks like the ID is generated from the name of the input.

Comment: Thanks @Marius your answer got me about 75% of the way there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample app where I have made the color of progress bar green using css.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(".progress-bar{background-color:#3c763d;}")),

    fileInput(inputId = "fileInp", label = "Input file:",multiple = FALSE,
               accept = c(
                 "text/csv",
                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                 ".csv"))

  )


  server <- function(input, output){


  }

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Using the above code you get something like this:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! I've spent about 6 hours on this problem and was so close yet so far, thank you!