# Set individual color of multiple progress bars in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

How would one go about setting the background color of multiple `fileInput()` progress bars in one `fluidRow()`. This is similar to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401763/colour-of-progress-bar-in-fileinput-shiny), however, this time it's just for multiple `fileInput()` objects. I want to do something like snippet below, but when I run this, instead of having the three individual colors, they are all the same color (#cfa646). *(Disclaimer, my html knowledge is non-existent, so I just wanted to demonstrate the concept with the given snippet.)*

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(column(4,
                  tags$head(tags$style(".progress-bar{background-color:#3c763d;}")),
                  fileInput("dataUpload_1","Label 1",width = "400px")),
           column(4,
                  tags$head(tags$style(".progress-bar{background-color:#bf37a4;}")),
                  fileInput("dataUpload_2","Label 2",width = "400px")),
           column(4,
                  tags$head(tags$style(".progress-bar{background-color:#cfa646;}")),
                  fileInput("dataUpload_3","Label 3",width = "400px")))
     

  )


  server <- function(input, output){


  }

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try, you are close, but as you mentioned, this does require some advanced CSS knowledge. Here is how:

[`:nth-of-type()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(
        '
        .myfiles .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(1) .progress-bar {background-color:#3c763d;}
        .myfiles .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(2) .progress-bar {background-color:#bf37a4;}
        .myfiles .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3) .progress-bar {background-color:#cfa646;}
        '
    )),
    fluidRow(
        class = "myfiles",
        column(4, fileInput("dataUpload_1","Label 1",width = "400px")),
        column(4, fileInput("dataUpload_2","Label 2",width = "400px")),
        column(4, fileInput("dataUpload_3","Label 3",width = "400px"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]